# Java Spring how to persist a date field in MongoDb as long

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

The project I'm working on has a collection where one of its fields is a *long* representing a date.
The representing Java class model has a *Date* field as a correspondence of the *long* one.

We used a *Json Schema* to create the collection and set the data format and required fields.

The data on the db has been imported using a json file and can be read through our Java application without problems: the driver is able to cast the *long* information in a *Date*, with no annotations or other stuff on the model class.

The problem came out when we needed to save this same document from the java application. It seems that the driver is not able to do the reverse cast, from Date to long.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` or some other class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I did the change from Date to Instant: now the saving goes well, but the data load broke with this error "org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.Instant]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Date to Instant and it didn't solved the saving problem, but on read it gives the  following exception:

> "org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
> converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to
> type [java.time.Instant]"

To solve this I needed to create a converter:

```
public class FromLongToInstantConverter implements Converter<Long, Instant> {

    @Override
    public Instant convert(Long source) {
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(source);
    }

}
```

This converter needed to be loaded by Mongo drivers so I had to create this class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new FromLongToInstantConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {

        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(
                new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory()), new MongoMappingContext());
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), converter);

    }

}
```

Which will be extended by the MongoConfig.java within the application.

This solution however leads to this bug: [Spring Boot - Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512580/spring-boot-illegal-reflective-access-by-org-springframework-cglib-core-reflec)

I did a similar converter for the saving operation and added it to the above *AbstractMongoConfiguration*:

```
public class FromInstantToLongConverter implements Converter<Instant, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convert(Instant source) {
        return source.toEpochMilli();
    }

}
```